# SQL Query return different result for parameter vs hardcoded value passed to HashBytes Function

Tags: sql, parameters, varchar, hashbytes

I need to pass values through a prameter to a HashBytes Function.  When I hardcode the values, and when I use a parameter, the results are different:

- I've tried to play with VarChar vs nVarChar
- I've tried to play with CHAR(13) and/or CHAR(10)
- I've copied the value of FileContents to NotePad and WordPad, and it seems correct in both.

```
--Read the values from the database into a parameter
DECLARE @FileContents  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableContents  table (TXT NVARCHAR(250))
insert into @TableContents (TXT) select TXT_0 from ZFICFIL
select * from @TableContents   -- Table contents

set @FileContents = ''
SELECT @FileContents = @FileContents + char(13) + TXT FROM @TableContents
-- Drop the first CR/LF
select @FileContents = right(@FileContents, len(@FileContents)-1)
select @FileContents

DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(MAX);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),'ZAPAY190800101000001,07/02/2019 14:46:24 PM
2,300,');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis)
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', @FileContents)
```

The table contents gives this:

```
ZAPAY190800101000001,07/02/2019 14:46:24 PM
2,300,
```

@FileContents gives this:

```
ZAPAY190800101000001,07/02/2019 14:46:24 PM
2,300,
```

This first HashBytes, give this result (hard-coded):

```
0xB1C23ED2F33F723D7C4FF23D4415B983F08E0C6C
```

This second HashBytes, give this result (parameter):

```
0x6A8C526D7BCD7BEA5789B53D526B8D5C77173EA2
```

If I don't read from the table , but 'hard-code' it as follows, then it works:

```
set @FileContents = 'ZAPAY190800101000001,07/02/2019 14:46:24 PM'
set @FileContents = @FileContents + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '2,300,'
```

I've tried to put the values in a file and read from a file, but that didn't work either.

```
set @FileContents = 'SELECT convert(varchar(MAX), *) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''C:\Temp\NB00002.TXT'',SINGLE_CLOB) x'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: MYSQL does not have nvarchar or + as a concat shortcut - are you sure this is a mysql question?

Answer (score 0):

**According to Microsoft documentation and the  function [HashBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :**

```
HASHBYTES ( '<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )  
<algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512
```

The single quotes are mandatory for the algorithm type and SHA1 output is 160 bits / 20 bytes. The input can be varchar,nvarchar, or varbinary. The output is returned as varbinary(Max 8000). **The max input is limited to 8000 bytes for SQL 2014(12.x) and earlier.**

Example:

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(32);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(32),'dslfdkjLK85kldhnv$n000#knf');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis);
```

*SQL 2016 and up have deprecated SHS and SHA1. Consider using checksum or binary_Checksum; Also for SQL 2014 and earlier the max input is 8000 bytes.